# Google Analytics - TEMPORARY 302 redirect - continue tracking old site

Tags: redirect, google-analytics, tracking

it is temporarily too slow and I would like to put a **302 - temporary redirect** to a **ANOTHER DOMAIN** . This will be so for about another 20 days.

If I just leave the **OLD TRACKING CODE (obtained for the OLD DOMAIN?)** intact, will Google be still tracking the page analytics?

Please suggest me if other any other ALTERNATIVE if BETTER, if I wish to CONTINUE tracking the old site UNDER THE SAME GOOGLE ACCOUNT **(so that I can compare the Analytics data )**

**thank u all for ur time :)**

Answer (score 0):

It's been almost a year since this question was asked, so I don't know if you're still trying to find the answer. That being said...

You can track the activity for the new site under the same Google account...just create a new profile and use that web property ID on the new site's pages. In the GA Dashboard:

- Press the Admin button in the upper right navigation bar
- Press the New Profile button, and fill out the appropriate information
- Reference that new UA number in your tracking code on the new site

As I recall, Google allows you create up to 50 profiles. Profiles are not directly attached to a domain. Since the context of the profiles is determine by the account owner, you have complete control as to where and how you collect the information.